# Copy all rows that match criteria from data set

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked all over the net for this and found quite a lot of similar issues, but none of the solutions seem to work for what I want. The dataset is below, and includes about 200 different rows. I am trying to create a macro button that when clicked will check to see if they are in Department A, and then copy all the row to a new sheet and also change page to that sheet.

The aim is to then setup 4 button, for Department A, B, C, D each on different sheets

[image]

thanks

Edit:

I don't want to have to select everything then click a button.

I would like just a button with a macro assigned that will check to see if they are in Department A, and if so copy the row over to sheet 2

thank

Comment: show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you considered that an Excel workbook is not the best solution? This could be implemented with a simple query of a database table. Since you're using MS Office, you may also have Access.

Comment: Just record a macro where you filter for each department, copy that data and paste to the correct sheet...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="a"

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
```

This does rely on your data all being as 1 block so that when you hit CTRL + A it selects it all, else you will have to manually specify your ranges.